# Is there a way to parse DAG files locally in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I would like to parse a DAG file locally. Is there a way to parse DAG files locally instead of waiting for the scheduler to catch it?

Reading this: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-serialization.html seems like it gets parsed when the Scheduler picks up a DAG file.

Using Airflow 1.10.15.

Comment: do you mean you want to run the dag? what do you mean my "parse it"?

Comment: @SimonD kind of like linting.

Comment: In that case, you can parse a dag file any time you want. Just run a python scrip that uses the dag file / folder as an input.